# Connection between lattice and vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, integer-lattices

We have the lattice $L\in\mathbb{Z^n}$, which is created from the vectors $x_1,...,x_n$. I have to give a definition of the rank of this lattice, in connection to the vector space associated with it.

My attempt: I am not at all sure, but as far as I understood the rank of the lattice is $n$ as far as the vectors above would be linearly independent, which from the formulation I don't know if we could conclude it. Then I don't know which vector space is meant as associated with this lattice. I thought about the one also created from these vectors, and if they are the basis of the lattice they would also be the basis of the vector space, and therefore have the same rank?

Thanks in advance for any sort of help

Annalisa

Comment: Typically, a lattice $L$ is defined as a subgroup of $\mathbb R^n$ (viewed as an abelian group) that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$ for some positive integer $n,$ so for any choice of a basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of $\mathbb R^n,$ we have that $L \cong \mathbb Z \langle e_1, \dots, e_n \rangle.$ In this case, I would argue that the rank of $L$ is simply $n.$

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)).

Comment: Put another way, the rank of the lattice $L$ is just the number of linearly independent vectors in your span.